# Custom parameter splitting formatting rules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have spent some time trying to find a way to automate a set of parameter splitting style guide and I have not had much luck.

I want the maximum line length to be 120 characters and I would like to format method params with the following order of preference.

`object.for(param1, param2, param3);`

```
object
    .foo(param1, param2, param3);
```

```
object.foo(
    param1,
    param2,
    param3);
```

The idea would be that it go in order of preference to find the way that fits.

Ideally this would be an intellij or checkstyle configuration but I am happy to use a library or write a plugin to achieve this.